# How to find data using using primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework. I need to find a record using its primary key.

I try like this.

```
tabCom com = db.tabCom.Find(3);
```

but there is error and it says

> 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to find the data using primary key. what the wrong with my code  or Is there is another way?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx) link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tabCom com = db.tabCom.Single(tab => tab.PrimaryKeyColumn == 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Find method was introduced in EF 4.1.

In EF 5 it has optimizations that will check the in-memory cache before going off to the database. Using `Single(entity => entity.PrimaryKey == id)` will not provide the same optimization.

Please check which version of EF your code is referencing.

Comment: As best I can tell, [`Find` is a member of `DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx). From OP: *error ... says 'System.Data.Objects.**ObjectSet**' does not contain a definition for 'Find'*

Comment: @ta.speot.is that means not only do you have to worry about which version of EF, but also if it is DB-first or Code-first, with each getting slightly different features.